# How To Select First Ancestor That Matches A Selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**General**:

How can I select the first matching ancestor of an element in jQuery?

**Example**:

Take this HTML block

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can remove a row in the table by clicking "Remove" using this jQuery code:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    return false;
});
```

This works, but it's pretty fragile. If someone puts the `<a>` into a `<div>`, for example, it would break. Is there a selector syntax in jQuery that follows this logic:

"Here's an element, now find the closest ancestor that matches some selection criteria and return it"

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That would be [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('tr').hide();
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer when SO lets me. You were too quick.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using `closest` as @Kobi points out (+1) as it seems to be the most concise way to do that. Just to point out, you can also use [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(this).parents("tr:first")
```

Comment: Good alternative. I just spotted the `:first` bit in selector, since `parents()`  (unlike `closest()`) returns *multiple* elements - all matching elements from the immediate parent upwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a selector to the parent argument I believe.

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
  $(this).parents("tr:first").hide();
  return false;
});
```

Or you can use closest as indicated by another answer.

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").hide();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: No, `parent` only looks at the immediate parent and not all ancestors.

Comment: `parent` traverses up a single level of the DOM tree, you would need `parents` instead. Also, the filter expression should be `tr:first` (no space).

Comment: @karim thanks, no coffee yet when I answered. Modified to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery 1.4, you can use [.parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) which will return all of the ancestors upto but **NOT** including the selected ancestor.

So in your case I would go with something like this:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parentsUntil("tr").parent().hide();
    return false;
});
```