# Finding ancestor with specific attribute or class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a DOM element `elem` that has an *ancestor* element which has the class `myClass` (alternatively an attribute with some name). The problem is that **I need to find this ancestor easily with jQuery**. Currently, I am stuck with ugly trial-and-error stuff like

```
var ancestor = $(elem).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

If the HTML code changes, the jQuery code easily breaks.

Is it possible to find the ancestor element with more elegant jQuery code?

Comment: Duplicate of [How To Select First Ancestor That Matches A Selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867022/how-to-select-first-ancestor-that-matches-a-selector)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Sorry, I missed that post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest). it will traverse up the DOM from the current element until it finds a parent element matching the selector you provide.

```
var ancestorByClass = $(elem).closest(".myClass"); // by class

var ancestorByAttribute = $(elem).closest('[href="#foo"]'); // by attribute
```

Answer (score 4):

Only `class` solution is presented, but not the `attribute` one.

I found my answer here: 
[jQuery find closest parent link with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984795/jquery-find-closest-parent-link-with-attribute)

Answer (score 3):

New method added by jQuery, the `parents` function allows you to check for all parents with selectors.

`var ancestor = $(elem).parents(".myClass");`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var ancestor = $(elem).closest(selector what are you looking for);
```

Comment: Thanks, dunno how I could have missed that one.