# jQuery find closest parent link with attribute

Tags: jquery, html, list, closest

I'd like to find the closest link with attribute `findme` from a children `.startpoint`.
Structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Point one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-findme="yipi">Point one</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="startpoint">My Startpoint</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(
        $('.startpoint').closest("*[data-findme]")
    );
});
```

Since the problem is, that the element `data-findme` is not a a parent element instead it is another child of a parent, my example will not find the element.
The example: http://jsfiddle.net/rjhgvxoe/

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need a selector like this:

```
$('.startpoint').closest("li:has(*[data-findme])")
```

That would query for the closest `<li>` element which contains an element with the attribute `data-findme`. To grab the anchor from there

```
$('.startpoint').closest("li:has(*[data-findme])").children('[data-findme]')
```

Comment: The asterisk is not needed. This works fine:

`$('.startpoint').closest('li:has([data-findme])')`

Also not sure why you switch between single and double ticks. Where possible, use single.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use:

```
 $('.startpoint').closest("ul").find('[data-findme]')
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wz7e5gj3/)**