# Find the first parent of a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Consider this sample html

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <span class="C">Sample text</span>
        <div class="D">
            <div class="E">Clickable Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some jQuery

```
$(".E").click(function(){
    //body
});
```

What is the easiest way to get a parent of `$(this)` that matches a selector? For example, say in the example I need to get the div where `class="A"`. At the moment because I know the structure of the html I could do

```
$(this).parent().parent();
```

But I'm looking for a way that would work regardless of the structure. Something along the lines of

```
$(this).findFirstParent(".A");
```

I hope I've been understandable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Select First Ancestor That Matches A Selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867022/how-to-select-first-ancestor-that-matches-a-selector).

Comment: @FelixKling, I was just about to +1 your answer, although not what I needed, I couldn't see a reason for the -1.

Comment: I guess because `.closest` is really the best approach here... but I missed the part in your question that the class `.A` is actually fixed, so nvm ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".E").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('.A'));
    /* console.log($(this).parents('.A')); works fine too */
});
```

See
http://api.jquery.com/closest/
http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Note that `parent()` is different than `parents()` method (the first one look for one ancestor only)

Comment: Thank you. I try googling but didn't know what phrase to be searching for. +1

Answer (score 3):

First Solution:

```
$(this).closest('.A')
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/closest/
This will return the first parent when traversing that matchs the selector.

Second solution:

```
$(this).parents('.A:first')
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/parents/
This will return all the parents that matches the selectors

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
$(this).closest(".A");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i would do it

```
$(this).parents("div.A")
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery parent selector might help you there. You can combine it with the class you are looking for. See the docs @
http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/