# how to get the href attr of a parent element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, find, parent, href, attr

i have this html tree example

```
<div class="auditions_date">
    <div class="new_green above_deadline"><a href="/auditions/2 ?>">Contact</a></div>
    <span class="aud_recommend"><a class="222" id="aud_recommend" href="#recommend_data">test</a></span>
</div>
<div class="auditions_date">
    <div class="new_green above_deadline"><a href="/auditions/3 ?>">Contact</a></div>
    <span class="aud_recommend"><a class="333" id="aud_recommend" href="#recommend_data">test</a></span>
</div>
```

when i click on the `test` link i want to get the `href` attr of the `a` tag

maybe:

```
$('a#aud_recommend').on("click", function() {
        var j = $(this).parent('.auditions_date').find('a').attr('href');
    console.log(j);
});
```

this doesn't seem to work properly.. any ideas?

thanks

Comment: (1) `.auditions_date` is not the parent of `a#aud_recommend` and (2) IDs must be unique. I suggest you to have a look at the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) and read carefully what `.parent()` is doing. Also, which `href` attribute do you want to get? There are two links in each `div`.

Comment: To supplement Felix Kling's comment, jQuery's .parent() only goes one level up the dom tree. You need to use .parents().

Comment: .parents() did the trick. thanks

Comment: When you click on test, which link do you want the href on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Select First Ancestor That Matches A Selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867022/how-to-select-first-ancestor-that-matches-a-selector)

Comment: @FelixKling in this case the `id` works ok. if i use a class it breaks. Maybe i do something wrong but it seems to work fine

Comment: It does not change the fact that duplicate IDs are invalid in HTML. Normally you'd simplify the selector to `$('#id')` (not `$('tag#id')`) but that would not pick up both links. Give both links a class  and select by that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#aud_recommend').on("click", function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var j = $(this).parents('.auditions_date').find('.new_green a').attr('href');

        console.log(j);
    });
});
```