# Find third parent jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works but the triple `.parent()` feels greasy and I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this

**NOTE**

The HTML is repeated multiple times on the page so I have to use classes and (this) in order to animate only the selected item

**jquery**

```
$('.view').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.innerContain').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 500); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mask">
    <div class="innerContain">
        <!-- Update -->
        <ul class="updateCSI">
            <span class="view">View</span>
        </ul>
        <!-- View -->
        <ul class="viewCSI">
            <span class="update">Update</span>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Select First Ancestor That Matches A Selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867022/how-to-select-first-ancestor-that-matches-a-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
$(this).closest('.innerContain');
```

In this case [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will help you to get the first element with class `.innerContain` whose ancestor of `.view` element when traverse up the DOM tree.

Comment: i changed the .view to (this), i got the idea of what he was saying i just needed to know closest

Answer (score 2):

I think `$(this).closest('.innerContain')` will do the same.

[**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/UYAGOBa/1/edit) (I'm using `.hide()` for the sake of the demo.)